# How to use the transform tool to rotate multiple layers?

Tags: animation, rotation, photoshop, layer

I have multiple layers that I used for animation.
Lets say I have "1111". Each 1 is a layer. I want each layer rotate 10 degrees.
Is there any way to do these automatically without selecting each one independently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a script to loop through all the layers in your document and rotate using something similar to below.

```
var j = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.layers.length; i++) {
        var lyr = app.activeDocument.layers[i];
        lyr.rotate(j)
        j = j + 10;
}
```